# Why aren't all changes made to Saas files working with Zen 5.x?

Tags: theming

I'm starting with theming and chose Zen 5.x for multiple reasons. Problem is, all this being new, I feel a little overwhelmed. I know how to "watch" the sub-theme directory with compass from the command line but all changes I make don't seem to make it through.

I've been trying to use Codekit to see if my assumption was about right and what I see are greyed out Sass files (all but **styles.scss**, as a matter of a fact). However, changes to **_layout-responsive.scss** do overwrite CSS files but **_layout-fixed.scss** don't.

[image]

Could someone please tell me more about all this?

Thanks

Comment: The files might be greyed out because they're being `@import`ed in the styles.scss file (a leading underscore is the naming convention for import files in SASS). If that's true, is there definitely an `@import` statement for all the `_*` files that you're expecting inside styles.scss?

Comment: Also I just downloaded Zen 5.1 and the file structure for the starterkit doesn't look anything like that, do you have the latest version?

Comment: Aha! Good catch. I'm indeed seeing an @import for each and every greyed out .scss file and one in particular is interesting: `@import "layout-responsive";` which would explain why changes made to **_layout-fixed.scss** don't work. Progress!

Comment: I've downloaded 7.x-5.x-dev because there are many differences with 7.x-5.1 and it's under heavy development.

Comment: Gotcha. Might be a silly question but do you have the fixed or responsive layout enabled?

Comment: So, assuming that `@import "layout-responsive";` in **styles.scss** is only what's needed to enable the responsive design, I'd say responsive? Furthermore, it goes along the lines of the README.txt files which claims that Zen is responsive by default.

Comment: Yep that sounds spot on, so I'd say you need to add your custom styles in the responsive include. Or, and probably better, a completely separate import file altogether to maintain nice separation from the default code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7228/discussion-between-vanz-and-clive)